# How to save a new document in mongodb using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm really trying to do this since i started to work with a mongo db but can't find the answer and how to achieve this, i'm think i'm close to understand it but need a little help; So i have a model like this :

```
public class UserInformationViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Nom")]
    public string NomUser { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prénom")]
    public string PrenomUser { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Entreprise")]
    public string EntrepriseUser { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Téléphone")]
    public string TelephoneUser { get; set; }
}
```

That i display like this in a modal :

```
<div id ="test" class="form-panel-modify">
    <div class="form-horizontal style-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.NomUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.PrenomUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EntrepriseUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EntrepriseUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.EmailUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInformationViewModel.TelephoneUser, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the modal :

```
            <div class="modal-content" style="height:600px;width:600px;text-align:center">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Informations</h4>
                    <p>Fill the form</p>
                </div>
                @Html.Partial("_ModalContent")
            </div>
```

So i want to take the different information in the form and to save them as a document in my mongo db, but i can't figure out how to do this .. everything i find on the web seems to be obsolete or not answering my question. And also by reading the doc on mongo site i can't achieve this, so if someone could help.

Would be great ! Thanks a lot, hope i'm clear.

EDIT :

```
public class ConnectionHandler<T> where T : IMongoEntity
{
    public MongoCollection<T> MongoCollection { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionHandler()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://IPADRESS";

        //// Acceder à la chaine de connection
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        //// Acceder au serveur
        var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();

        //// Acceder à la BD 
        const string databaseName = "BD NAME";
        var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        //// Acceder aux collection la BD (tables en langage relationnel...)
        //// NB: le nom des collections est mis en minuscule et pluralisé
        MongoCollection = db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the HTML code you show is relevant, and whether the documentation you find applies to your situation depends on which version of the driver you're using.

Comment: Can you share the relevant server side code that contains a reference to MongoDB driver code?

Comment: I made an edit, this is how i connect to my db

Answer (score 0):

The *document* would be your model. So you need to use the mongodb driver to access the collection for you model:

```
var usersCollection = db.GetCollection<UserInformationViewModel>("UserInformationCollection");
```

And with that you can use the MongoDB operations on the collection, like Insert:

```
public async Task Create(UserInformationViewModel user, CancellationToken token)
{
    await usersCollection.InsertOneAsync(user, cancellationToken: token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little ? Do i put this in my controller ?
Ok i assume it will go in user collection ?

Comment: I would add the code accessing MongoDB driver to a specialized Data Access class. A UserRepository or something. Give an instance of that UserRepository to your UserController.

Comment: And what about the reference in my proj ? i'm using the mongo ref byt still have the message "The name MongoCollection does not exist in curent context"

Comment: Did you add the `using MongoDB.Driver` directive for the mongo driver?

Comment: Yes i have, but still i'm not really understanding how it work since my application already as a connection with the mongodb so why would i recreate it ?

Comment: You don't need to create a new one. My code was an example to illustrate the getting the collection for the specific collection. Go ahead with your current one,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111238/discussion-between-christian-pliso-and-bruno-garcia).

Comment: I don't get the logic here, my var usersCollection, where do i need it to be ?